# curl command not found even though curl is installed

Tags: curl

I install curl .but it says curl command not found.

osgi> curl -X POST -H "content-type: application/json" -d '{"sweet": "Jaffa Cake","batch": {"batch id": "batch1","count": 10}}'http://localhost:5005/SweetProductionEP 
gogo: CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: curl